# How do i convert Date to TimeInterval so I can use the if statements

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsdateformatter

This is my code:

```
if let date = messages?.date{
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"

            //let elapseTimeInSeconds = NSDate.timeIntervalSince(date)
            let elapseTimeInSeconds = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: (date as? Date))

            let secondsInDays: TimeInterval = 60 * 60 * 24

            if elapseTimeInSeconds > secondsInDays {

                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE"
            } else if elapseTimeInSeconds > 7 * secondsInDays {

                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy"
            }

            timeLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date as Date)
        }
```

this is the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Date?' to expected argument type
>   'TimeInterval' (aka 'Double')

the error is on this line:

```
let elapseTimeInSeconds = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: (date as? Date))
```

I've tried what I know and nothing has worked. Please help.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can directly access it through property `timeIntervalSinceNow` of [`Date`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/date) also there is no need to use `NSDate` in Swift 3 use directly `Date` and `date(from:)` method of `DateFormatter` return instance of `Date?` not `NSDate?`.

```
let timeInterval = date.timeIntervalSinceNow
```

And you can get `TimeInterval` between two dates using method `timeIntervalSince(_:)`.

```
let timeInterval = date1.timeIntervalSince(date2)
```

Comment: Hey Nirav. Thank you for the quick answer. I had Date.TimeIntervalSince(date) before and its type was (Date) -> TimeInterval which made it so the types didn't match therefore I couldn't compare them in If statement. So you switched them around it made it work.

Comment: My code works now but Its skipping If statement for days that are more than a day or seven days. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3.0**

You Need write code this:

```
let elapseTimeInSeconds = Date().timeIntervalSince(date as Date) 

Strong!!! Date() or NSDate().timeIntervalSince(date as Date)
```